# Is there a way to force Dark Mode on a website on macOS for Safari?

Tags: html, macos, safari, macos-darkmode

I've attempted

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme dark)
```

but it doesn't seem like that works for macOS on Safari? Works just fine on iOS Safari so I'm kind of confused.
Is there a way to create like a fallback in case that doesn't work and the page defaults to a white page? Basically if `@media (prefers-color-scheme dark)` doesn't work, and the page defaults to light mode, is there any way to create a fallback so that it'll show it in dark mode before loading the page with light mode?

Answer (score 0):

Im not positive about what you want but I think setting the "@media (prefers-color-scheme: light){" to a dark background would function as a fallback.
something like https://codepen.io/jonneal/pen/vzPwWo      `@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {`

Comment: Nevermind, just thought about the fact that if I wanted my page to use only dark mode, I could just use style="background-color: black;" to get the same thing

Comment: Simple enough! I thought you were trying to trick those dark mode extensions. This would be the workaround for that.